# How can i add an image to a header of a xlsx file using xlsxwriter and python?

Tags: python, unix, libreoffice, xlsxwriter

I want to add an image to the header of the xlsx but it's showing nothing on the generated file (our application picks a .csv, then converts to .xlsx using .py file with xlsxwriter, and then to .pdf using a libreoffice command)

We've already tried with different image formats and sizes but it made no difference.

Also tried with the examples from the library (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_headers_footers.html?highlight=set_header) with no luck.

We used the `worksheet.insert_image()`, it adds the image but not in the header. This is our current result: https://ibb.co/QNXv8bM

We want to add the image directly on the header (maybe using the `set_header()` ) but so far our tries with this method hasn't produced any results. When we use the `set_header()` to place the image it shows nothing on the header.

Here is a piece of the python file that we are using:

```
def create_worksheet(workbook, data, image, p_header_text):
    '''
    Creates and formats worksheet
    :param workbook: Main workbook
    :type workbook: xlsxwriter.Workbook
    :param data: dict with data to use in the worksheet
    :type data: dict
    data example:
    data = {'headings': [head1, head2, ..., headn], 'rows': [[data1, ..., datan], ...]}
    :return: Nothing
    '''
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    ### Page Setup
    worksheet.set_margins(top=1.4)
    worksheet.set_landscape()
    worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
    #worksheet.set_paper(9)  # 9 = A4
    worksheet.fit_to_pages(1, 0)
    ### Header and footer
    header_text = p_header_text
    #worksheet.set_header('&C&16&"Calibri,Bold"{}'.format(header_text))
    worksheet.set_header('&L&G', {'image_left': '/home/reports/LTA-logo.jpg'})


    worksheet.set_footer('&L&D&RPage &P of &N')
    #worksheet.insert_image('A1', '/home/reports/LTA-logo.jpg', {'x_offset': 0, 'y_offset': 0})
    #worksheet.set_header('&C&G', {'image_left': '/home/reports/LTA-logo.jpg'})

    ### Create table
    create_table(worksheet, data)
```

**Note**: The `worksheet.set_header('&C&16&"Calibri,Bold"{}'.format(header_text))` works fine, it shows the text on the header. The problem is when we try to put the image...

The expected result is to make the image appear in the header, left aligned with the title as shown on this picture: https://ibb.co/vQTytK2

**Note 2**: For business reasons (company) i cannot show the data on the print screens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with XlsxWriter. You just need to build the format string in the right way with the `&L` left part and the `&C` centre part.

For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('headers_footers.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Image')

# Adjust the page top margin to allow space for the header image.
worksheet.set_margins(top=1.3)

worksheet.set_header('&L&[Picture]&C&16&"Calibri,Bold"Revenue Report',
                     {'image_left': 'python-200x80.png'})

workbook.close()
```

Note, I use the more explicit `&[Picture]` in the example but `&G` works as well.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Edited the code with your suggestion but still not putting the image :/

Comment: Here is the link with the full script (is just 170 lines) http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user45_bkdvNJiWYy_2.py

Comment: Maybe create other .py file to insert just the image in the header ? Or manipulate the final PDF and insert the image there?

Comment: If you run my example does it work? The image is in the examples dir of XlsWriter: [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/master/examples/python-200x80.png).

Comment: Tested now, it generates the headers_footers.xlsx but when i open it its blank.. see screenshot: https://ibb.co/G9QGZQR

Comment: The headers aren't visible in that view. You need to change to "View -> Page Layout", or "Page Layout -> Page Setup -> Header/Footer" or Print Preview.

Comment: Ok it works! The .xlsx is being generated corretly but the pdf still doesn't show the header. Here is the command that picks the .xlsx and converts to PDF: "soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir " + directory + " " + fullpath;

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: No. That is a completely different question/problem. Are you sure that soffice supports this.